# Devise redirect to custom action on sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I'm using Devise for user authentication, and want to have the user redirected to a custom action that I have set up for the User class called 'myaccount'. However, I can't get the syntax right - I'm getting varying errors with everything I'm trying.

This code might show you what I'm trying to acheive (it doesn't work though):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'myaccount', :id => current_user.id and return
  end
```

And the routes:

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  devise_for :users 

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'myaccount'
    end
  end
```

Apologies, it's probably quite a newbie question - but how do I either change my redirect, or add a new route so that e.g. user_sign_in_path would work?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

In case anyone else finds this question, this is what worked for me:

```
url_for :controller => '/users', :id => current_user.id, :action => 'myaccount'
```

which is the correct order that I need it in. I had to put a slash infront of the controller name to make it use that instead of the Devise controller.

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in to have more detailed explenation. I hope it helps

Comment: I had looked at that, but it didn't quite give me the syntax I was after. For anyone finding this question, this page: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for gave me some details as to what I needed to do - i.e. to put the slash before the controller name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to  call `redirect_to`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  { controller: 'users', action: 'myaccount', id: current_user.id }
end
```

if that doesn't work, wrap that up in `url_for` and that should work :)

Comment: Tried both, and get the same result with either. I've added an update to the question - how come it appears to be attempting to use the devise controller instead of the one I have specified? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, got it - needed to put a slash in front of the controller name. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can actually use `myaccount_user_path(current_user)`